# Should pkg .a files be gitignored for golang

Tags: git, go

Since .a files in the pkg directory are compiled from .go source, should these be ignored in git?   What would be the reason for keeping .a files in SCM?

When I look at the recommended .gitignore files for go, .a files are not excluded.

https://github.com/github/gitignore

Comment: Normally some _sub_folder of `src` are managed by git but never `pgk`. Read How to Write Go Code.

Comment: How are you building packages that .a files end up in your source tree in the first place?

Comment: I guess I should have mentioned that the issue is that go code is only part of the overall solution.   I have a number of other things (batch files, config files, database test scripts, etc.) that are all part of the overall solution.   I assumed that the .gitignore would have accounted for a larger scoped repository.

Answer (score 3):

Generally build products would not be tracked in Git, since these can be regenerated from files that *are* tracked.

In the case of Go, the compiled package files typically don't end up in the same place as the source files (`pkg/...` vs. `src/...`), so while it would indeed be correct to not track them, there is no need to explicitly add them to an ignore list.

Comment: It is part of an overall larger repository scope, and I assumed that .gitignore would have accounted for that.   So then I can do pkg and bin without concern.